# How can I make a compile conditional on PYMAJOR_VERSION?

Tags: cython

This won't compile.

```
from cpython.version cimport PY_MAJOR_VERSION
# ...

IF PY_MAJOR_VERSION < 3:
    def __getslice__(self, long i, long j):
        return self._arr[i:j]
```

With ...

```
jnius/jnius_nativetypes.pxi:65:19: Error in compile-time expression: TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < int()
```

What's an alternative?